# How to get the list item ID of a nested library folder using PnP PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, pnp-powershell, metadata

I am trying to add metadata to document library folders created using the `Add-PnPFolder` command. I've been using the `Set-PnPListItem` command to do this, which requires the folder's list item ID.  Using

```
Get-PnPListItem -List $LibraryName -UniqueId $folder.UniqueId
```

to retrieve the ID works when the folder is at the root of the library, but fails to return anything for nested folders.  I've tried

```
Get-PnPListItem -List $LibraryName | Where-Object {$_.FieldValues.Title -eq $foldername}
```

which works, but gets prohibitively expensive as the library grows.  Is there a better way to get metadata onto a folder item that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Is it the same metadata for all folders or are there any special cases?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind getting the ID from the SharePoint UI instead of using PnP PowerShell?
If no, you can show the OOB ID column in the view.

[image]
[image]
If you have a nested folder structure, you can search on the top search box by the folder name and you can easily get the folder ID from UI.
[image]

Comment: That might be an option, however I have a large number of files to add to this library and am using PnP PowerShell to do so.  I'd like to add the metadata via the script and not have to go back and semi-manually tag 1500+ folders.  Regardless, thank you for your answer!